# Issue with send_keys in Selenium

Tags: selenium

I am trying to fill up textbox using Selenium.

```
description=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'add 
description')]")
description.click()
description = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@type='text']")
description.send_keys(""+str(description))
```

For some reason the variable value of description isnt passed to the textbox but webelement id and session id which is :

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="f2943bc99f2fbbec90c3fa9c0cb68e20", element="0.3535547756904527-5")>
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: driver.find_element_by_xpath("YOUR_XPATH").send_keys("YOUR_STR")

Answer (score 0):

try with this code :

```
description.send_keys("""Just a testing """)
```

**OR**

```
description.send_keys(str(description.text))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your code correctly 'description' contains a web element. So your `send_keys` is essentially typing the web element in string form.

From the (unofficial) documentation:

> **find_element_by_xpath(xpath)**
> Finds an element by xpath.
>
> Args: xpath - The xpath locator of the element to find
>
> Returns: WebElement - the element if it was found
>
> Raises: NoSuchElementException - if the element wasn’t found
>
> Usage: element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(‘//div/td[1]’)

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html